# this.onchange is not a function

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I am trying to use type to initialize the value accessor methods, but I am getting the error: this.onchange is not a function. Following is my code:

```
type TOnChangeCallBack = (value: string) => void;
type TOnTouchCallBack = () => void;

onChange: TOnChangeCallBack;
onTouch: TOnTouchCallBack;

registerOnChange(fn: TOnChangeCallBack): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: TOnTouchCallBack): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
```

Comment: [Fine here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg8gOwMIAsCGCDmEloDZ4BCaAxgNZQC8UAFAG74CuEAXFAM7ABOAllgJRUAfFDoB7HgBMA3AChQkWIhhjGJFLgLFyVWoMojxUubJJ407dlABiYsVADesqC6hjk6LBACEbeB4xsTSJSMjlXNwQVNRRfJSjVdWDtMNlnVy4ITB5OCC5EVECIGgAzBD8CzyD8EPJ+NiNJR3SIl2AUHIA6d0KvXTLw1wBfNIjM7Nz8hJiISVLy+OikmpT60Qkmp1bXdq73JZR+hEGXEaGgA)

Comment: More info would be appreciated